# What NoClassDefFoundError and wrong name means to JPA?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm working on MAVEN and JPA in a web project. Somehow I got a strange error on NoClassDefFoundError as shown below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: WEB-INF/classes/org/huahsin/WebEngineering/Role (wrong name: org/huahsin/WebEngineering/Role)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.internalFindClass(AppClassLoader.java:214)
    at [internal classes]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.NativeScanner.getClassesInJar(NativeScanner.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addScannedEntries(Ejb3Configuration.java:487)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:861)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:75)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:287)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    ... 27 more
```

I have my `persistence.xml` put under `src/main/resources/META-INF` and the content is like below:

```
    <persistence-unit name="WebEngineering" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>org.huahsin.WebEngineering.Role</class>
        <class>org.huahsin.WebEngineering.User</class>
        ...
        ...
    </persistence-unit>
```

In my POM.xml, I'm using these library:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I check on the WAR file, I got the `Role.class` seen in `WEB-INF/classes/org/huahsin/WebEngineering` folder. I wasn't sure whether I got the persistence file place in the right folder or is actually I'm using the wrong JPA library in MAVEN?

### Problem has already been solved

This problem is cause by the `persistence.xml` wasn't put in the right place. It suppose to put inside `src/` directory instead I wrongly put under the `resources/` directory. My initial though was that since I'm using MAVEN, the `persistence.xml` suppose to be inside `resources/` directory, but in fact I was wrong.